How to save python loop output to an excel file
I have an excel file (input.xlsx) that contains two columns (id and url).
I performed webscrapping on all the url and performed text analysis on the texts.
I have functions that calculates the positive score, negative score, polarity etc.
I want to create an output file(output.xlsx) that will contain all the above results but my script is printing same output in all the rows but it is printing the correct output inside the function.
Example:
Columns: Id, url, positive score, negative score, polarity etc
Rows: Rows will contain the output of each function.
Expected Output:
Positive Score(column) : 23, 70, 43, 35 (rows)
Actual Output:
Positive Score(column) : 35, 35, 35, 35 (rows)
MY FUNCTIONS:
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import glob
import codecs
import os



data_ex = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")
urls = data_ex.URL
url_ids = data_ex.URL_ID

folder = "files_folder2"
Path(folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

#WRITING THE EXTRACTED CONTENTS TO TEXT FILES
for url, url_id in zip(urls, url_ids):
    res = requests.get(url, timeout=60)

    page = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    article_title = soup.find_all(name="h1", class_="entry-title")

    article_texts = []
    article_details = []

    for details in article_title:
        text = details.getText()
        article_writeup = soup.find(class_="td-post-content tagdiv-type").getText()

        file_path = Path(folder, f"{url_id}.txt")
        with pathlib.Path.open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(f"{text}\n {article_writeup}")



#POSITIVE WORDS
def positive_score(content):
    #tokens = tokenz(text)
    pos_score = 0
    for token in content:
        if token in filtered_positive_dictionary:
            pos_score += 1
    return pos_score

positive_scores = []

# Cleaned texts
os.getcwd()
new_texts_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'new_texts')

for root, folders, files in os.walk(new_texts_folder):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        with codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as info:
            new_content = eval(info.read())  # Convert string to list
            pos_score = positive_score(new_content)
            positive_scores.append(pos_score)


#NEGATIVE WORDS
def negative_score(content):
    neg_score = 0
    for token in content:
        if token in filtered_negative_dictionary:
            neg_score -= 1
    return neg_score * -1
#negative_result = negative_score(new_content)
negative_scores = []

# Cleaned texts
os.getcwd()
new_texts_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'new_texts')

# Loop through cleaned texts and filter out stop words
folder_name = "negative"
Path(folder_name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for root, folders, files in os.walk(new_texts_folder):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        with codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as info:
            new_content = eval(info.read())  # Convert string to list
            neg_score = negative_score(new_content)
            negative_scores.append(neg_score)



#POLARITY SCORE
import numpy as np

def polarity_score(positive_scores,negative_scores):
    polar_score = (positive_scores - negative_scores)/((positive_scores + negative_scores)+0.000001)
    return polar_score


The above codes prints the correct outputs.
My Excel Function:
data_collection = {
    'URL_ID': url_ids, #(this is the ID from the excel file where the website is)
    'URL': urls, #(this is the website url from the excel file)
     'POSITIVE SCORE': positive_score, #(this is the positive score gotten from each of the urls)
'NEGATIVE SCORE': negative_score #(this is the negative score gotten from each of the urls)
}
excel_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_collection)
excel_data_df.to_excel("Outputput.xlsx", index = False)

I want the excel file to contain the URL_ID and URL associated to each POSITIVE SCORE.
i.e: url:www.testing.com, url_id: 6474, positive_score: 60

The issue you're encountering arises because you are calling the positive_score function once for each file but using only the last result for all entries in your DataFrame. To solve this, you need to store the results for each file in a list and then use that list when creating the DataFrame.
try this :
import os
import codecs
import pandas as pd

filtered_positive_dictionary = {'good': 1, 'excellent': 1, 'happy': 1}

def positive_score(content):
    pos_score = 0
    for token in content:
        if token in filtered_positive_dictionary:
            pos_score += 1
    return pos_score

url_ids = []
urls = []
positive_scores = []

new_texts_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'new_texts')

for root, folders, files in os.walk(new_texts_folder):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        with codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as info:
            new_content = eval(info.read())
            pos_score = positive_score(new_content)
            url_ids.append(file)
            urls.append(f"file://{path}")
            positive_scores.append(pos_score)

data_collection = {
    'URL_ID': url_ids,
    'URL': urls,
    'POSITIVE SCORE': positive_scores
}

excel_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_collection)
excel_data_df.to_excel("Output.xlsx", index=False)


I have another issue with the url_id. I'm getting the url_ids and urls from an excel sheet. I noticed my script is not scraping one of the sites, probable because of wrong link. Now my url_ids is 8 in length whereas my positive score is 7 in length.... So, the excel output is giving an error about mismatched length.

Can you post your code here?

Sorry, i've been offline for sometime now.

Please i've updated the code.
